# HTTP Get Request from web client fails

Tags: rest, cxf

I am using 
cxf.jaxrs apache-cxf-3.1.4 to write my REST server.
Client : angular js

Works with Chrome Advance Rest Client app and java rest client. But fails for web app,

Server code:

```
Class ABC {
     protected Server() throws Exception {
            JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
            sf.setResourceClasses(CustomerService.class);
            sf.setResourceProvider(CustomerService.class, 
                new SingletonResourceProvider(new CustomerService()));
            sf.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/");
            sf.create();
    }
}
```

Resource Code:

```
class BCD {

@GET
@CrossOriginResourceSharing(allowAllOrigins = true, allowOrigins = {"http://localhost:56696", "http://localhost:9001", "*"}/*, allowCredentials = true*/,allowHeaders="*")
@Path("/offices/{id}/")
@Produces("text/plain")
    public String getCustomer(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper ();
        return om.writeValueAsString("ABC");
    }
```

Client error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/office/offices/123. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:56696' is therefore not allowed access.

In Web App:

index.html code

$scope.sendName = function () {
            var headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With',
                 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Accept': '*/*'                };

```
        var response = $http({
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers,
            url: 'http://localhost:9001/office/offices/1',
            responseType: "json"
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log("Auth.signin.success!")
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Auth.signin.error!")
        });
```

How to resolve this issue